# Im creating a new instance variable of the view controller, how to i message the original one

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why wont my UILabel display a NSInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666739/why-wont-my-uilabel-display-a-nsinteger)

Yesterday I asked why my label wouldn't update, it would always display 0 and someone told me it was because i was making a new ivar of the View Controller and it wasn't the actual View Controller (line 4 of game controller). How do I update the UILabel on the actual screen? can I some way to instantiate the viewController is the actual ViewController or do I have to write a method asking what is the gameController ivar how much the score is? I'm clearly lost at this point.

in ViewController

```
-(void)setScore:(NSInteger)gameScore{
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gameScore];
scoreLabel.text = string;
NSLog(@"the score is %i", gameScore);
}

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender{
gameController = [[GameController alloc] init];
//in my header is GameController* gameController;
}
```

in GameController

```
-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
//in header ViewController* viewController;
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gameLoop:)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];

//in the header CADisplayLink* displayLink;
}
return self;

}

-(void)gameLoop:(CADisplayLink *)sender{
deltaScore++;
if (deltaScore >= 20) {
deltaScore -= 20;
score++;
//deltaScore and score are NSIntegers
[viewController setScore:score];
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just exactly your other question?

Comment: I just want this question answered, I keep checking the internet but I can't find any way to do it, and I'm sure it can happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `GameController` class, you're creating a new instance of `viewController` instead of calling the original one. Consider making the main viewController class a delegate of GameController and making a method in the `GameControllerDelegate` protocol that communicates from GameController to viewController.